# How to add informative text to menu strip separator in vb.net or C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

In Window form. I want to add informative text to the Menu separator. Can anyone suggest how to do that?
for example separator should appear like below

```
Menu Item1 
Menu Item2 
----- Separator title ----- 
Menu Item3
Menu Item4
```

After Lots of attempts I am only able to add simple separator. Any help would be Great

Comment: Doing so may surprise your customers,as this isn't a generally accepted thing to do.

Answer (score 3):

You can create your own menu separator

```
Public Class TextToolStripSeparator
    Inherits ToolStripMenuItem

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property CanSelect() As Boolean
        Get
            Return DesignMode
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Overrides Property Text() As String
        Get
            Return MyBase.Text
        End Get
        Set
            value = value.Trim("-"C, " "C)
            MyBase.Text = "---- " & value & " -------"
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

It will automatically appear in the "Insert" context menu if it is defined in the same project.

---

I also tried to override the `OnPaint` Method. Without success. There is some magic going on that prevents owner drawn objects to appear.

---

**EDIT**:

Finally, after some research and a lot of trial and error I found a more satisfying solution. This is how the result will look

[image]

First, we create our own tools strip separator class.

```
Public Class TextToolStripSeparator
    Inherits ToolStripMenuItem

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property CanSelect() As Boolean
        Get
            Return DesignMode
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property HasDropDownItems() As Boolean
        Get
            Return False
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

As you can see, it is very simple. The more complicated part goes in our own `MenuStrip` class. Here we provide a customized `ToolStripRenderer`, which, in the end, does the job.

```
Public Class MenuStripEx
    Inherits MenuStrip

    Public Sub New()
        Me.Renderer = New ToolStripRendererEx()
    End Sub

    Private Class ToolStripRendererEx
        Inherits ToolStripProfessionalRenderer

        Protected Overrides Sub OnRenderItemText(e As ToolStripItemTextRenderEventArgs)
            Const  flags As TextFormatFlags = TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter Or TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter

            Dim item As ToolStripItem = e.Item
            If TypeOf item Is TextToolStripSeparator Then
                Dim textWidth As Integer = TextRenderer.MeasureText(item.Text, item.Font).Width
                Dim rect As Rectangle = e.TextRectangle
                rect.Width = e.ToolStrip.Width - rect.Left - 3
                TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, item.Text, item.Font, rect, Color.DimGray, flags)

                Dim y As Integer = rect.Y + rect.Height \ 2
                Dim margin As Integer = (rect.Width - textWidth) \ 2
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.DarkGray, rect.X, y, rect.X + margin, y)
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.DarkGray, rect.Right - margin, y, rect.Right, y)
            Else
                MyBase.OnRenderItemText(e)
            End If
        End Sub
    End Class
End Class
```

Comment: Finally here is a VB version. Sorry for providing a c# version first. I did not see your VB tag.

Comment: Thanks for this; I needed a C# implementation so I've added one below in case anyone else needs it.

Comment: Does this work with dynamic contextMenuStrip? I have tried but I dont have an idea how to implement this. Can you provide some usage example?

Answer (score 1):

So you don't need a separator, you need a disabled menu item!

Answer (score 1):

I needed to create a C# implementation of Olivier Jacot-Descombes's solution, so here it is in case anyone else needs it. In my case I needed it for a `ContextMenuStrip` rather than a `MenuStrip` but it works just the same, the only difference is the name I've used.

```
public class TextToolStripSeparator : ToolStripMenuItem
{
    public override bool CanSelect { get { return DesignMode; } }

    public override bool HasDropDownItems { get { return false; } }
}

public class ContextMenuStripEx : ContextMenuStrip
{
    public ContextMenuStripEx()
    {
        this.Renderer = new ToolStripRendererEx();
    }

    private class ToolStripRendererEx : ToolStripProfessionalRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnRenderItemText(ToolStripItemTextRenderEventArgs e)
        {
            const TextFormatFlags flags = TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter | TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter;

            ToolStripItem item = e.Item;

            if (item is TextToolStripSeparator)
            {
                int textWidth = TextRenderer.MeasureText(item.Text, item.Font).Width;
                Rectangle rect = e.TextRectangle;
                rect.Width = e.ToolStrip.Width - rect.Left;
                TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, item.Text, item.Font, rect, Color.DimGray, flags);

                int y = rect.Y + rect.Height / 2;
                int margin = (rect.Width - textWidth) / 2;
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.DarkGray, rect.X, y, rect.X + margin, y);
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.DarkGray, rect.Right - margin, y, rect.Right, y);
            }
            else
            {
                base.OnRenderItemText(e);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible. Not with built-in menustrip anyway. I don't know whether there are 3rd part controls that you could use for this one. 
If you must need it, just make the title as you have shown in your question. Just don't write any code for any event of that menustripitem.