# using Class TextToolStripSeparator

Tags: vb.net

Hi Imm trying to use the Class TextToolStripSeparator, as provided here.
[How to add informative text to menu strip separator in vb.net or C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9176239/how-to-add-informative-text-to-menu-strip-separator-in-vb-net-or-c-sharp)

I am having dificulty implementing the solution. I have placed the classes in and have created a separator but I can't seem to figure out how to place the text. I am using a dynamicaly created ContextMenuStrip in a datagridview from a right click.

```
 Dim menu As ContextMenuStrip = New ContextMenuStrip
     Dim NewSep1 As New TextToolStripSeparator
     menu.Items.Add(NewSep1) 
     menu.Show(Me, pt.X, pt.Y)
```

when I tryto add text like  `menu.Items.Add(NewSep1("-test-"))` I get an error:

> Error 1   Class 'myprog.TextToolStripSeparator' cannot be indexed because it has no default property.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to set the seperator's `.Text` property.

```
Dim NewSep1 As New TextToolStripSeparator
NewSep1.Text = "-test-"
menu.Items.Add(NewSep1)
```

Comment: I would swear black and blue I tried that ! Thank you. It works! Nice effect!